# SQL Complex update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to update a table column white the same data that currently exists in that column plus add data from one column from another table. The tables in question are in 3N.

I am attempting to do a complex update by concanting data from one column in a principle table into a column in an existing table.

```
update Catelog.Component SET Name = p.Number 
          FROM Catelog.Part p                                JOIN 
               Catelog.ComponentPart cp ON p.ID = cp.PartID  JOIN 
               Catelog.Component c      ON cp.ComponentID = c.ID  
          where p.BrandID = 1003
          AND ct.Name='Door' + '|'+ Name;
```

If you'll notice the Name column that I am setting I am resetting the data that already exists in that column plus prefixing the PartNumber.

Basically I need to prefix the existing data in the Name column with the part number from the part table.

Right now SQL is giving me the ambiguous error.

Plus, I do not think that the rows would be set correctly the way I've got this update structured.

What is the best way to do joined updates like this?

Comment: 'SET Name = p.Number' this is where your ambiguous error is coming from, which Name should be updated?

Comment: @msmucker0527 no, I believe it is coming from the last line.

Comment: The Ambigious error is coming from the last line. At the Name column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Update  C
Set C.Name = CAST(p.Number as varchar(10)) + '|'+ C.Name
FROM Catelog.Component C
JOIN Catelog.ComponentPart cp     
    ON p.ID = cp.PartID  
JOIN Catelog.Component c  
    ON cp.ComponentID = c.ID  
where p.BrandID = 1003
AND ct.Name='Door' + '|'+ C.Name;
```

I'm not sure about where last Name belongs (from which table, it's not clear)

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE c
  SET c.Name = RTRIM(p.Number) + '|' + c.Name 
FROM Catelog.Part AS p              
INNER JOIN Catelog.ComponentPart AS cp     
  ON p.ID = cp.PartID  
INNER JOIN Catelog.Component AS c  
  ON cp.ComponentID = c.ID  
WHERE p.BrandID = 1003
  AND ct.Name = 'Door|'+ c.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do this:

```
update Catelog.Component 
SET Name = p.Number + '|'+ Name
FROM Catelog.Part p              
JOIN Catelog.ComponentPart cp  ON p.ID = cp.PartID  
JOIN Catelog.Component c       ON cp.ComponentID = c.ID  
JOIN Catelog.Category ct       ON p.CategoryID = ct.ID
where p.BrandID = 1003
    AND ct.Name='Door';
```

Comment: This will still have an ambiguous column error (since it seems Name is in more than one of the joined tables) and I think your where clause no longer matches correctly. I also think you should be updating the alias and not the base table.

Comment: Your right. The table alias is the only way to do this type of update, and I appreciate everyone's help!